# 'System.StackOverflowException' on setter

Tags: c#

I have some dto object which I want to sent over the wire using wcf. In this simple case it has FirstName, LastName and Name. Name returns firstname and lastname in conjuction.

Normally I would'nt use settter for Name property but I have to since otherwise it cannot be serialized, so I tried with internal but I'm getting error on Name setter

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException'
>   occurred in LibSys.WebServices.dll

```
[DataMember]
public string FirstName { get; set; }

[DataMember]
public string LastName { get; set; }

[DataMember]
public string Name  {
   get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName); }
         internal set { Name = value; }
}
```

Comment: In fact, `Name` should not be serialized at all. You already serialize `LastName` and `FirstName`. When you deserialize your object and call `Name` property it will calculate its value from those 2 properties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your setter calls itself recursively. If the value of `Name` is calculated from the other properties, you should probably omit the setter entirely. Since it's a calculated entirely from other properties, you probably don't need it to be serialized either.

If having a setter is an absolute must, you can just create an empty setter like this:

```
public string Name  {
   get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName); }
   internal set { }
}
```

Comment: letting the setter empty is not really good as just make the `Name` get-only.

Comment: @KingKing In original question property is `DataMember`.

Comment: @KingKing This is supposed to be a readonly property anyway, right? And what would it matter if it's not callable from user code (without reflection)? I agree it's bad practice, though. Just offering an alternative.

Comment: Yes, It is better to throw `InvalidOpertaionException` or `NotSupportedException` than empty setter. User will feel value set successfully, but really not.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I don't see that as an issue. The setter is internal. A user would not be able to set the value without using reflection. If they are circumventing the public interface and fiddling around with non-public methods, why should it matter what they expect to happen?

Answer (score 5):

The bug is the setter of `Name`.  It unconditionally calls the setter of `Name` and hence will result in a stack overflow.

If `Name` is a combination of `FirstName` and `LastName` then you should split the `value` in the setter and assign the two values to `FirstName` and `LastName` respectively

```
public string Name  {
   get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName); }
   internal set 
   {
      var values = value.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
      FirstName = values[0];
      LastName = values[1];
   }
}
```

That's a pretty rough example, before checking in I'd add some error checking to ensure the string actually had a space in it.

Really though I question why this property needs a setter at all.  It's really a calculated property.  As such it should be responsible for displaying values only.  Setting the values should be done directly on the properties from which the value is calculated.

Comment: Too much work in setter. Also I would not expect `IndexOutOfRangeException` to be thrown in setter. Omitting setter is just fine.

Comment: @Leri i agree that it's a calculated property and probably shouldn't be serialized at all.  But if it *must* have a setter then this is the best way to implement it

Comment: Well, being marked with `DataMemberAttribute` means property _must_ have setter. However, it may be remained empty.

Comment: @Leri that seems much worse.  Having a setter which does nothing would be extremely confusing to a consumer of the type.  The setter should either do work or not be present

Comment: I agree. Since properties that construct `Name` property are serialized there's no need of extra traffic and on the receiving end it's pretty trivial to recalculate property value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
public string Name  {
   get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName); }
         // you're setting Name to value, that's recursive, you should add another variable.
         internal set { Name = value; }
}
```